# Lambdas in C++03

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, lambda, c++03

So, I am trying to replace the following code (C++11):

```
struct test {
    const char *n;
    int i;

    std::function<int(void)> read;
    std::function<void(int)> write;
};

#define define_test(n, i, bodyRead, bodyWrite)  \
    { n, i, []() { bodyRead; }, [](int v) { bodyWrite; } }

std::initializer_list<test> tests = {
    define_test("test1", 1, return 1, v = 2),
    ...
};
```

with a C++03 compatible code that gives the same effect:

```
struct test {
    test(const char *_n, int _i, boost::function<int(void)> _read, boost::function<void(int)> _write) {
        n = _n;
        i = _i;
        read = _read;
        write = _write;
    }

    const char *n;
    int i;

    boost::function<int(void)> read;
    boost::function<void(int)> write;
};

#define define_test(n, i, bodyRead, bodyWrite)  \
    ( n, i, []() { bodyRead; }, [](int v) { bodyWrite; } )

std::vector<test> tests;
static void init_tests(void) {
    tests.push_back(define_test("test1", 1, return 1, v = 2));
}
```

With no doubt, The Visual C++ Studio 2008 Express SP1 compiler rejects the lambda expressions, using boost wouldn't help it either, except was bind() and the lambda boost got, which I am not exactly sure how I would do it with this.

To elaborate more on this, I want to also be able to use  like so:

```
using namespace boost::assign;
static std::vector<test> tests;
static void init_tests(void) {
    push_back(tests)
        define_test(...)
        ...;
}
```

that means structs with static functions won't be of much help either e.g.:

```
#define define_test(n, i, bodyRead, bodyWrite)  \
    struct {
        static void fn##n(void) { bodyRead; }   \
        static void fnw##n(int v) { bodyWrite; }    \
    };  \
    ( n, i, boost::bind(&fn##n), boost::bind(&fnw##n, boost::placeholders::_1) )
```

That's because I am writing a ton of this and C++11 was so easy.

Comment: I fear, you are looking for convenience disturbing maintenance of code. (Passing a non trivial function as a macro parameter)

Comment: @DieterLücking Well, I ended up redesigning this whole thing :( gotta love C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cobble something together with Boost Phoenix, for example.

```
s_tests.push_back(test ( "test1", 1, phx::val(1), phx::ref(v) = arg1*1 ));
s_tests.push_back(test ( "test2", 2, phx::val(2), phx::ref(v) = arg1*2 ));
```

It will not achieve the natural C++ syntax, but at least it will be pretty full featured (it supports exceptions, while_, for_, switch_, locals, bind() etc.):

- [Lazy Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/starter_kit/lazy_operators.html)
- [Lazy Statements](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/starter_kit/lazy_statements.html)
- [Construct, New, Delete, Casts](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/starter_kit/construct__new__delete__casts.html)
- [Lazy Functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/starter_kit/lazy_functions.html)
- [More](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/starter_kit/more.html)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bc8a371eb64c923)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>

struct test {
    const char *n;
    int i;

    boost::function<int(void)> read;
    boost::function<void(int)> write;

    test(char const* n, int i, boost::function<int(void)> read, boost::function<void(int)> write) 
        : n(n), i(i), read(read), write(write)
    {}
};

#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace boost::phoenix::arg_names;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

namespace mocks {
    static int v;

    typedef std::vector<test> test_t;

    test_t const& tests() {
        static test_t s_tests;
        if (s_tests.empty())
        {
            s_tests.push_back(test ( "test1", 1, phx::val(1), phx::ref(v) = arg1*1 ));
            s_tests.push_back(test ( "test2", 2, phx::val(2), phx::ref(v) = arg1*2 ));
        }

        return s_tests;
    }
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {


    for (mocks::test_t::const_iterator it = mocks::tests().begin();
            it != mocks::tests().end(); ++it)
    {
        test const& test = *it;
        std::cout << "'" << test.n << "'\t" << test.i << ", " << test.read() << ", ";

        test.write(42);
        std::cout << "mock v: " << mocks::v << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
'test1' 1, 1, mock v: 42
'test2' 2, 2, mock v: 84
```

Comment: Made the sample **[truly live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bc8a371eb64c923)** and c++03 proof. (Of course, there were many other details c++11 specific.)

Comment: Sorry if my comment was a little vague.  Let's say I want to save some typing, by e.g. `#define define_test(n, i, bodyRead, bodyWrite) (n, i, boost::phoenix::val(bodyRead), boost::phoenix::ref(v) = boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1; if_ (v) [ bodyWrite; ] }` or maybe just `[ bodyWrite; ]`

Comment: I'm not sure what typing you're trying to save. I don't think you be able to include "natural C++ statements" directly in your dreamed macro (this is kind of the selling point of of lambdas). However, in my opinion, the Boost Phoenix does a pretty decent job coming close. I'd suggest to per-use the linked pages, or to rethink your requirements :)